# The term "'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" error installing Selenium Python bindings

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I am trying to install Python Selenium, `pip install selenium`, but I get this error:

> File "", line 1  pip3 install selenium  ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: what is the solution for invalid syntax

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: It says "running scripts is disabled".  You don't have permission.  Ask your system administrator.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75152111/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "`^^^^^^^`" indicates there was more than one line in the original. Was there?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install -U PySide
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

...implies that system was unable to locate *`pip`*.

---

### Solution

This error is shown on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) when user tries to use `pip` in the command prompt. To address this error on windows [os](/questions/tagged/os) you need to add the path of the *Python Interpreter* to the system **`Path`** variable.

To see a list of things you can do with `pip`, you can execute the command on your terminal:

```
py -m pip
```

---

Additionally, you may need to upgrade [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) as follows:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then you can simply install or upgrade the [Selenium Python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) as follows:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Comment: i am getting the same error how do i fix it >>> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Add the path of the Python Interpreter to the system Path? If so, try to restart/reboot the system.

Comment: I tried restarting and deleting python and trying to download a different version but the result is the same error